# Merging dataframes of uneven length in R based on match variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

I know questions about merging dataframes in R are common, but I have not found a solution to my problem after a grueling search.

I have two dataframes in R: one contains information about a population (here, organizations, n=~4200) including their regions, states, counties, program titles, etc; the other contains only county and state information for 509 unique county-state combinations.

I need to match the large dataframe with the smaller dataframe, so that I ultimately end up with a merged data frame where N rows is equal to the smaller data frame.

For example, the large dataframe (n=~4200 rows) looks something like this:

```
County        State    Court     Program  Court.Type  ...   ...  ...
String1       CT       Court1    String1  1
String1       AL       Court2    String2  2
String1       CA       Court3    String3  3
String1       IL       Court4    String4  2
```

The small dataframe (n=509) looks something like this:

```
State   County    QuantData   ...   ...
AL      String1   xxxxx
NY      String1   xxxxx
NM      String1   xxxxx
```

I need to match the large dataframe to the small dataframe so that I can incorporate the small dataframe's columns into a new dataframe lined up with the values from the large dataframe.

Ultimately, I need to end up with 509 rows of matched data in the new dataframe.

To make matching easier, I did this:

```
courts$match = paste(courts$State,courts$County) # courts is the large df
sub$match = paste(sub$State,sub$County # sub is the small df
```

Then, I did this:

```
df = merge(courts, sub, by="match", all=F) # returns only 4 rows

df = merge(courts, sub, by="match", all=T) # returns well over 4000, but without matching the values
```

Now, I should say that it is possible for multiple state-county matches to occur in the large data set, as some counties within the states provide multiple services of interest, often at overlapping locations.

However, in the small data set, these are unique state-county pairs. So, it is possible to end up with slightly more than 509 in a final merge, but definitely not 4000(+).

I hope this makes sense -- thank you all for your help!

Comment: Try `all.y = T` instead of `all = T`.

Answer (score 0):

You already tried all.x = T? If you use all = T, it keep all the x and y values in the table.

```
all <- data.frame(County=rep("String1",4), State=c("CT", "AL", "CA","IL"))
lookup <- data.frame(State=c("AL", "IL", "NM"), County=rep("String1", 3), QuantData=c(1,2,3))

all$key <- paste(all$State, all$County, sep="")
lookup$key <- paste(lookup$State, lookup$County, sep="")

result <- merge(all, lookup, by="key", all.x=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers!

It turned out be a problem with the structure of the master data file itself. I appreciate your solutions!